# PHP replace text within a <h1> </h1> tag

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm using AJAX to call a PHP file which will effectively edit particular bits of content within another HTML file. My problem is that I'm not sure of the best way of targeting these particular areas.

I figured some sort of unique identifier would need to attached to the tag that needs to be edited or in a comment perhaps, and then PHP simply searches for this before doing the replacing?

Comment: Use a html parser like simplehtml

Comment: Don't whatever you do even think about using a [re̸g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆e̿̔̉x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: did a quick Google of simplehtml and it look's promising! I'll explore further. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [simplehtml](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for this.

You can change all `<h1>` to `foo` like this:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
foreach($html->find('h1') as $element) 
{
  $element->innertext = 'foo';
}
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplehtmldom framework allows you to search and modify the DOM of a HTML file or url.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
// Create DOM from URL or file $html =
file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
        echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Another nice library is querypath. It is very similar to jquery:

```
 qp($html_code)->find('body')->text('Hello World')->writeHTML();
```

https://fedorahosted.org/querypath/wiki/QueryPathTutorial